Структура сохраняемого xls файла, через LibreOfice
Вопрос заключается в том, чем обусловлено создание двух "Root Entry" при сохранении таблиц в LibreOffice, при том, что при создании подобного файла через MS Excel, корневой вход один. Я могу игнорировать сегмент на который не ссылается число в заголовке файла, или он для чего-то нужен?
